# issue with class methods / async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, static-methods, zustand

Using Zustand in my React project, I am defining the global authentication states as you see in the code snippet. I am also defining an Auth API to run the auth methods. However, for some strange reason, even when the response status is 200 and when I make it into the `if (response.status === 200)` check, the if-block lines after the `this.setLogin` line do not run, which means:
`success=true` does not run.
`console.log("authenticated")` also does not run.
If I put them before the `this.setLogin`, they both run.

**The Zustand store:**

```
import { create } from "zustand";

type AuthStore = {
  id: number | null;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  accessToken: string;
  setLogin: (token: string, id: number) => void;
  setLogout: () => void;
  test: () => void;
};

export const useAuthStore = create<AuthStore>((set) => ({
  id: null,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  accessToken: "",
  setLogin: (token, id) =>
    set({ isLoggedIn: true, accessToken: token, id: id }),
  setLogout: () => set({ isLoggedIn: false, accessToken: "", id: null }),
  test: () =>
    set((state) => {
      console.log(state.accessToken);
      return {};
    }),
}));
```

**The auth API:**

```
import { AxiosResponse, isAxiosError } from "axios";
import { UserAccountType } from "../types/userInfo.type";
import api from "./api";
import { useAuthStore } from "../store/authStore";

interface User {
  token: string;
  id: number;
}

export class AuthApi {
  private static setLogin(token: string, id: number): void {
    useAuthStore().setLogin(token, id);
  }

  static async login(userCred: Partial<UserAccountType>) {
    let success = false;
    let errorMessage = "";
    try {
      const response = await api.post<User>("/auth/login", userCred, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const token = response.data.token;
        const id = response.data.id;
        this.setLogin(token, id);
        console.log("authenticated");
        success = true;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (isAxiosError(err)) {
        const status = err.response?.status;
        console.log(err);
        switch (status) {
          case 401:
            errorMessage =
              "Invalid Email or Password. Try again or click Forgot password to reset it.";
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = `${err.message}. Please try again.`;
        }
      }
    }

    return { success, errorMessage };
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know what a `static` method on a `class` is? hint: use `AuthApi` instead of `this` to access one - though, the fact that it's a private method too, you may need to do something else too ...

Comment: @JaromandaX and @tao thank you. In my code, the `login` method is also a static method, which means I can call another static method within `login` using `this`. I don’t think that’s the issue. Even using the `AuthApi.setLogin` did not resolve the issue.

Comment: *using the AuthApi.setLogin did not resolve the issue* ... because setLogin is private (you using typescript I assume) - try `this.#setLogin`

Comment: hmm, if you are using typescript - your code should actually work (I think)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i’m using Typescript. It’s a very strange situation because I have examined the code all day and it looks like it must work! Unless it’s an issue that’s specific to Zustand.

Comment: Suggests `useAuthStore().setLogin(token, id);` is throwing an error that you are not seeing for some reason